# Split array in n arrays with certain length

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have this:

```
<:cmd:409342761179938838> <:nobot:409342761246916610> <:haha:409342761272344578> <:rrrr:409342761431728139> <:aaa:409342761439854593> <:fff:409342761503031296> <:woah:409342761532391424> <:swon:409342761549037568> <:owoah:409342761595043850> <:sss:409342761662414848>
```

Convert it to this array:
using .split(' ')

```
[ '<:cmd:409342761179938838>',
  '<:nobot:409342761246916610>',
  '<:haha:409342761272344578>',
  '<:rrrr:409342761431728139>',
  '<:aaa:409342761439854593>',
  '<:fff:409342761503031296>',
  '<:woah:409342761532391424>',
  '<:swon:409342761549037568>',
  '<:owoah:409342761595043850>',
  '<:sss:409342761662414848>' ]
```

But i don't know how to split it several arrays so each will have 100 symbols in it

like this:

```
[ '<:cmd:409342761179938838> <:nobot:409342761246916610> <:haha:409342761272344578>' ],
[ '<:rrrr:409342761431728139> <:aaa:409342761439854593> <:fff:409342761503031296>' ],
[ '<:woah:409342761532391424> <:swon:409342761549037568> <:owoah:409342761595043850>' ],
[ '<:sss:409342761662414848>']
```

p.s. i tried use `.match(/.{1,100}/g);`
but i got this

```
[ '<:cmd:409342761179938838> <:nobot:409342761246916610> <:haha:409342761272344578> <:rrrr:409342761431 '], ['728139>... etc ']
```

and i don't want to split `<:rrrr:409342761431728139>`

Comment: What do you want here?  Do you want _exactly_ 100 characters?  Well, that's probably not possible.  Do you want less/more than 100 characters, but as close as you can get?  Something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes i want to get as close as i can to 100

Comment: Start with your original `.split()` array. Loop through the array, concatating elements to the strings in the result array. Whenever the length gets above 100 start a new string.

Comment: Do you really need each string to be in its own nested array? Or just one array of these strings.

Comment: @Barmar one array splitted with ',' will work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the first suggested approach, there is a functional way, using the `reduce` function:

```
const arr = str.split(' ')
  .reduce((acc, item) => {

    const idx = acc.length ? acc.length - 1 : 0

    const tempStr = `${acc[idx] || ''} ${item}`;

    return tempStr.length <= 100
      ? Object.assign(acc, { [idx]: tempStr })
      : [...acc, item];

  }, []);
```

Comment: Good alternative. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Split the string on spaces. Then concatenate each string to a result until it would be over 100 characters long, then you push it onto the result array.

```js
var str = '<:cmd:409342761179938838> <:nobot:409342761246916610> <:haha:409342761272344578> <:rrrr:409342761431728139> <:aaa:409342761439854593> <:fff:409342761503031296> <:woah:409342761532391424> <:swon:409342761549037568> <:owoah:409342761595043850> <:sss:409342761662414848>';
var array = str.split(' ');
var result = [];
var curstr = '';
array.forEach(s => {
  var newstr = curstr + (curstr != '' ? ' ' : '') + s;
  if (newstr.length > 100) {
    result.push(curstr);
    curstr = s;
  } else {
    curstr = newstr;
  }
});
if (curstr != '') { // Get the last string, which wouldn't have been pushed in the loop
  result.push(curstr);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think instead of minimum 100 chars, OP is asking for nearest char closest to 100 but not exceeding 100. That's why the first element in the array is 80

Comment: @D.Lene My code was making strings >100 characters long. I changed it to push just before it gets to 100, so it produces the same result you wanted.

Comment: @Isaac I realized that and changed it.

Answer (score 0):

**@D.Lene**, according to the output provided in the question. I have written the below code which gives youur output.

> **Note:** Please do not forget to look at code executed on **Node REPL** after the below code. It will give you a clean understanding of each and every line.
>
> And leave comment if the below code does not satify your need by  provide more outputs (that you actuially need for some specific inputs) as I am not counting for 100 characters as your provided output array's elements are not exactly of length 100 (it's 80, 78, 81, ...) which is clear in **Node REPL** testing.
>
> If you are still looking for 100 characters then based on your provided data input(s) & output(s), I will need to change the code.

```js
var data = "<:cmd:409342761179938838> " +
          "<:nobot:409342761246916610> " +
          "<:haha:409342761272344578> " +
          "<:rrrr:409342761431728139> " +
          "<:aaa:409342761439854593> " +
          "<:fff:409342761503031296> " +
          "<:woah:409342761532391424> " +
          "<:swon:409342761549037568> " +
          "<:owoah:409342761595043850> "+
          "<:sss:409342761662414848>"

var arr = data.split(' ')
console.log(arr)
/*
  [ '<:cmd:409342761179938838>',
    '<:nobot:409342761246916610>',
    '<:haha:409342761272344578>',
    '<:rrrr:409342761431728139>',
    '<:aaa:409342761439854593>',
    '<:fff:409342761503031296>',
    '<:woah:409342761532391424>',
    '<:swon:409342761549037568>',
    '<:owoah:409342761595043850>',
    '<:sss:409342761662414848>' ]
*/

var mainArr = []

while(arr.length) {
      mainArr.push(arr.splice(0, 3).join(' '))
}

// Pretty printing array 
// (This is the o/p which is specified in the question, here I forgot everything about 100 characters)
console.log(JSON.stringify(mainArr, null, 4))
/*
  [
      "<:cmd:409342761179938838> <:nobot:409342761246916610> <:haha:409342761272344578>",
      "<:rrrr:409342761431728139> <:aaa:409342761439854593> <:fff:409342761503031296>",
      "<:woah:409342761532391424> <:swon:409342761549037568> <:owoah:409342761595043850>",
      "<:sss:409342761662414848>"
  ]
*/
```

Finally look at the below code executed on **Node REPL** to understand few of the above basic statements.

```
H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects\Stk>node
>
> var data = "<:cmd:409342761179938838> " +
...           "<:nobot:409342761246916610> " +
...           "<:haha:409342761272344578> " +
...           "<:rrrr:409342761431728139> " +
...           "<:aaa:409342761439854593> " +
...           "<:fff:409342761503031296> " +
...           "<:woah:409342761532391424> " +
...           "<:swon:409342761549037568> " +
...           "<:owoah:409342761595043850> "+
...           "<:sss:409342761662414848>"
undefined
>
> arr
[ '<:cmd:409342761179938838>',
  '<:nobot:409342761246916610>',
  '<:haha:409342761272344578>',
  '<:rrrr:409342761431728139>',
  '<:aaa:409342761439854593>',
  '<:fff:409342761503031296>',
  '<:woah:409342761532391424>',
  '<:swon:409342761549037568>',
  '<:owoah:409342761595043850>',
  '<:sss:409342761662414848>' ]
>
> arr[0]
'<:cmd:409342761179938838>'
> arr[0].length
25
>
> arr[1].length
27
>
> arr[2].length
26
>
> arr[3].length
26
> arr[4].length
25
> arr[5].length
25
> arr[6].length
26
>
> var mainArr = []
undefined
>
> while(arr.length) {
...       mainArr.push(arr.splice(0, 3).join(' '))
... }
4
>
> mainArr
[ '<:cmd:409342761179938838> <:nobot:409342761246916610> <:haha:409342761272344578>',
  '<:rrrr:409342761431728139> <:aaa:409342761439854593> <:fff:409342761503031296>',
  '<:woah:409342761532391424> <:swon:409342761549037568> <:owoah:409342761595043850>',
  '<:sss:409342761662414848>' ]
>
> mainArr[0]
'<:cmd:409342761179938838> <:nobot:409342761246916610> <:haha:409342761272344578>'
>
> mainArr[1]
'<:rrrr:409342761431728139> <:aaa:409342761439854593> <:fff:409342761503031296>'
>
> mainArr[2]
'<:woah:409342761532391424> <:swon:409342761549037568> <:owoah:409342761595043850>'
>
> mainArr[0].length
80
> mainArr[1].length
78
> mainArr[2].length
81
>
```

Thanks.